# How to seed RRDtool from file with timestamps?

Tags: statistics, graph, plot, rrdtool

I have a file with timestamps for hits on a system. How can I feed this into the [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) database (or other similar solution), so that I can plot a time graph?

Comment: What is the format of your file. is that in CSV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ABSOLUTE type datasource and for every event you see do a

```
rrdtool update log.rrd $stamp:1
```

If you want to track different events, have multiple rrd files. You can then pull them all together into a single graph.

$stamp is the unix time format (seconds since 1970) so you have to convert the timestamps in your logfile first.